# Unmarshalling - internal (child) element is null

Tags: java, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have the following XML received as a response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    xmlns:tns="**********">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:RemitInterfaceAPIResponse
            xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
            <return xsi:type="tns:RemitInterfaceSoapObject">
                <TransactionNumber xsi:type="xsd:string">12345</TransactionNumber>
                <Status xsi:type="xsd:string">STRING</Status>
                <StatusDesc xsi:type="xsd:string">String string string.</StatusDesc>
                <Code xsi:type="xsd:string">STR</Code>
            </return>
        </ns1:RemitInterfaceAPIResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

RemitInterfaceAPIResponse.java:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "RemitInterfaceAPIResponse")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class RemitInterfaceAPIResponse {

    @XmlElement(name = "return")
    public RemitInterfaceAPIResponseObject soapObjects;

    public RemitInterfaceAPIResponseObject getSoapObjects() {
        return soapObjects;
    }

    public void setSoapObjects(RemitInterfaceAPIResponseObject soapObjects) {
        this.soapObjects = soapObjects;
    }
}
```

RemitInterfaceAPIResponseObject.java:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class RemitInterfaceAPIResponseObject {

    @XmlElement(name = "TransactionNumber")
    private String transactionNumber;
    @XmlElement(name = "Status")
    private String status;
    @XmlElement(name = "StatusDesc")
    private String statusDesc;
    @XmlElement(name = "Code")
    private String code;

    public String getTransactionNumber() { return transactionNumber; }

    public void setTransactionNumber(String transactionNumber) { this.transactionNumber = transactionNumber; }

    public String getStatus() { return status; }

    public void setStatus(String status) { this.status = status; }

    public String getStatusDesc() { return statusDesc; }

    public void setStatusDesc(String statusDesc) { this.statusDesc = statusDesc; }

    public String getCode() { return code; }

    public void setCode(String code) { this.code = code; }
}
```

When I'm trying to unmarshall into an instance of `RemitInterfaceAPIResponse`, I'm getting a valid `RemitInterfaceAPIResponse` instance of an object but `soapObjects` is null.

Here's my unmarshalling code:

```
SOAPMessage message = MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage(null, new ByteArrayInputStream(responseString.getBytes(StringConstants.UTF_8)));
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(RemitInterfaceAPIResponse.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
return (T) unmarshaller.unmarshal(message.getSOAPBody().extractContentAsDocument());
```

Help would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: One thing we can see is that the element `RemitInterfaceAPIResponse` is in the namespace `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/` (which is very weird, as this is usually only used for the SOAP envelope elements), and the element `return` does not have a namespace. Maybe your Java classes put them both into the namespace?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I think you might be right. My `package-info` says: `@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)`. The package containing both of the classes. Is there a way to say "Namespace is relevant only to root element"?

Comment: I am not that familiar with JAXB, but you could try with `@XmlElement(name="return", namespace="")`. Or simply put both classes into separate packages.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose no luck with `@XmlElement(name = "return", namespace = "")` :-(

Comment: Then ... sorry ... please do some research yourself. You maybe have a clue right now.